# How can I import from ReadItLater to Instapaper?

Tags: import, instapaper, pocket

I've all but migrated to Instapaper from ReadItLater, but can't accomplish the import and am bummed by the options of using both for a while or (gasp) manual click-add import of a couple of hundred links.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Was it really a need to migrate? I am using Pocket for old bookmarks and InstAPaper for new bookmarks.

Comment: I asked this question over at AskDifferent and you can find what you're looking for [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17229/is-there-a-way-i-can-import-readitlaters-exported-html-file-into-my-instapaper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st get the RSS feed from ReadItLater. Then register in [Instascriber](http://instascriber.com) using your Instapaper username & password. Add ReadItLater feed to instascriber. Now you can get your ReadItLater feed to Instapaper, at least most recent links